# Disable TideSDK installer dialog when first opening a app?

Tags: tidesdk

Is there anyway to disable the TideSDK installer dialog popup when first opening your app. I am submitting an app to a 3rd party distribution site and it was rejected because of this.

Please help?

Answer (score 1):

You could use tidebuilder.py and pass the -n parameter to it. The final command would be:

```
./tidebuilder.py -n -d {output dir} {source project dir}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create the application in bundled mode. There would not be any installer dialog popping up while installing the application. It is likely that you have created a networked installer and while installing and running first time its trying to fetch the modules from internet by popping up the installer dialog.

Can you provide some more details about your application, modules used by the same, are u creating net installer or bundled, which platform you are on ?

Also if possible describe the commands which you are using to create the application. This would be helpful for further investigating the issue.

Comment: I'm on MacOS 10.7.5 and I'm using TideSDK Developer to package the app with runtime.